# how to get files from the server in react

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, download, blob

I have method in my Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/photos")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPhotos(){
        List<Photo> photoList = photoService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(photoList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And it returns the array from the database: 
`[{"id": 1,"name": "photo1.jpg","file": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wC...(byte[])"},{...},...]`
I know that one file is done like this:

```
.then(response => {
   response.blob().then(blob => {
      let url=  window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
});
});
```

But how to do with array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use response.json() instead.

```
.then(response => {
    response.json().then(responseJSON => {
        // responseJson should be an array that you can iterate on and manipulate individual objects and parse relevant keys. 
    });
});
```

Comment: @macmar22 You can accept and/or upvote if it worked :)